# Change of Company and country - EU blue Card

Tags: germany, eu, blue-card, working

I am holding a German EU blue Card and I have received an job offer from Latvia. EU blue Card I am holding only for 2 months now.
But I am planning to movie to Latvia for my new job.

What are the steps to be taken?

Answer (score 1):

your current Blue Card EU is a German one. It has no impact and validity in Latvia. I guess you need to apply for a visa : [Applying for a visa](https://www.mfa.gov.lv/en/consular-information/applying-for-a-visa) at the latvia embassy in Germany site. See the Q&A for details as their rules may be different to Germany.